# WPF - Highlight one row in ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listbox, wpf-controls

Im quite new to the WPF, so this may be a simple question.

I have ListBox with with defined style, font and whole rest of the stuff. I want to highlight one row there, but the problem is that all rows are added programatically, so I can't just edit the row properties and change for example foreground collor (that would be enough). I know the target row ID, but I can't find any way to access its ListItemBox object. To access the specific item I used:

```
((MyClass)(Playlist.Items[i])).MyProperty = 0; //Access the i element of ListBox named Playlist
```

Is it even possible? I searched for the solutions here and on other sites, but nothing helps in my case.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:
I don't mean to select the row, but to change it's foreground color.

Comment: Create a proper Data Item model for your items and a proper `DataTemplate` for the `ListBoxItems`.

Comment: I'm with @HighCore on this one. If you define a specific View Model class for the items in your ListBox, and you have the ListBox's ItemSource bound to a collection of these items, you can go through that collection to find the item, and the View Model item class can expose whatever properties it need to in order to support the bindings you need.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a DataTemplate and a DataTrigger.  Your DataTemplate defines what you want each item in your listbox to look like (TextBlock, Image, etc).  The DataTrigger will flag specific data conditions on each item in your list box and change the style of DataTemplate accordingly (like Foreground color).  This is assuming your ListBox is databound to a collection of MyClass with a property named MyProperty.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyProperty}"/>
<DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ID}">
        <DataTrigger.Value>
            303216
        </DataTrigger.Value>
      <DataTrigger.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Navy"/>
      </DataTrigger.Setters>
    </DataTrigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>

</DataTemplate>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.triggers.aspx

Comment: @kittyPL - could please mark this answer as correct if it helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Design The listbox control template from SCRATCH using Blend it will help you to change foreground color of selected item in listbox. Also Blend is wonderful tool for WPF UI designs so check it.

Comment: I don't want to change properties of selected item - I know how to do this. I need to change property of item using only its id.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't implement a proper MVVM solution for this, you can get the `ListBoxItem`s from the `Items` property of the `ListBox`. If the `ListBox` is data bound (using the `ItemsSource` property), each of the `ListBoxItem`s that is automatically generated will have its `DataContext` property set to an item in the collection that is bound to the `ItemsSource` property. You can evaluate it there. I wouldn't recommend this approach, however. Use a proper MVVM solution if possible.

```
var id = ...;

var item = (from ListBoxItem i in ListBox1.Items
            let data = (MyClass) i.DataContext
            where data.Id == id
            select i).FirstOrDefault();
if (item != null)
    item.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
```